# Using global variables as arguments of rect

Tags: python, pygame

I create two global variables x,y .I use them as x,y coordinate of a rectangle.
When I want to change their value.I have to call them as rect.x or rect.y .Why it is so?
Why can't I call them just by x or y

```
x = 0
y = 0
t= [5,5]
rect= pygame.Rect((x,y),(50,55))

rect.x += t[0]
rect.y += t[1]
```

Why not just `x += t[0]`

Comment: So what is the nature of the problem? What *does* happen when you do: `x += t[0]`?

Comment: The values of `x` and `y` are copied to the `pygame.Rect` object. The object doesn't reference to variables `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0):

You're only using that `x` and `y` to *initialize* the `Rect` object's *seperately stored* `x` and `y` variables. They're not the same variable. Since they're separate, you have to refer to them in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

well, you are creating the variable `rect` as an object of a class, with the attributes of `x` and `y`

just modifying the `x` variable wont map the the attributes of the object its self, you have to modify them separately!

by calling upon:

```
rect.x
rect.y
```

you are calling the `x`, and `y` attributes of the `rect` object

---

one thing you could do just to see how it works:

```
x += t[0]
print(x)
print(rect.x)
```

you should notice that `rect.x` has not changed